# Converting String (containing characters and integers) to integers and calculating the sum in JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, char, int, charat

- This method calculates the sum of all digits in a String of length 10. The String has to be of the form "12345?789x" or "12?4567890", where '?' can lie anywhere and has a value of 0, 'x' (if present) lies at the end of the String and is equal to 10.
- The sum should be calculated as follows: 
  For "11432?789x", sum = (10*1)+(9*1)+(8*4)+(7*3)+(6*2)+(5*0)+(4*7)+(3*8)+(2*9)+(1*10) = 164.
- This code works perfectly for numbers ending with 'x', but for those that don't, it returns the value of sum as 0. For example, for "111?111111" instead of returning 48, it returns 0.
- I'm not able to find out the error. Please help.

  ```
  public static int sum(String input,int l){
  int sum=0;
  int temp=0;
  char a;
  for(int i=0;i<l;i++){
      a=input.charAt(i);
      if(a=='x'){
          temp=10;
      }
       else if(a=='?'){
          temp=0;
      }
      else{
      temp = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i));
      }


      sum = temp*(10-i)+sum;
  }
  return sum;
  }
  ```

Comment: "12345?789x" or "12?4567890", where '?' can lie anywhere and has a value of 0, 'x' (if present) lies at the end of the String and is equal to 10." your example is not even of this form

Comment: "111?111111" from your code is result 48

Comment: @Fabinout it does, the numbers can be anything from 1 to 9, just not 0 and 10 (cause they are ? and x)

Comment: @Fabinout '?' can lie anywhere between positions 0 to 8. 'x', if present should only lie at position 9 (i.e. at the end). 'x' can be absent too.

Comment: @Manu so you iterate over your string and just multiply the first item by 10, the second by 9, etc?

Comment: @Fabinout, I didn't ask the question, but, yes.

Comment: @maskacovnik for "111?111111", result should be 48, but it returns it as 0.

Comment: No, your code results 48 @ryan321, make sure if `l` (length) is not `0` while passing it as parameter

Comment: "111?111111" returns 48. Maybe you didn't set l to 10.

Comment: As the others are saying, `sum("111?111111")` is in fact returning 48. Maybe you should declare a variable `int l = input.length()` instead of taking it as a parameter?

Comment: @Manu : just replaced l by 10 (in the for loop), and its working now. Even though I passed l as 10 in the method argument.. Don't understand what happened. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you provide the code where are you calling this method @ryan321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this test and it's green:

```
@Test
public void removeme() {
    String input = "111?111111";
    int sum = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        char a = input.charAt(i);
        if(a == 'x'){
            temp = 10;
        } else if(a == '?'){
            temp = 0;
        } else {
            temp = Character.getNumericValue(input.charAt(i));
        }

        sum = temp * (10 - i) + sum;
    }
    assertThat(sum , is(48));
}
```

I suggest you remove the argument `l` and just use input.length(), as I did.

Answer (score 2):

Your example:

```
111?111111
```

Expected result: `48`

if I call:

```
String input = "111?111111";
int result = sum(input,input.length());
```

result is 48

Maybe you call method like this:

```
String input = "111?111111";
int result = sum(input,0);
```

There result is `0`

Or second parameter of sum is corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Funny though i m using the same code posted by you AND i am getting the correct answers. BTW the example cited by you 
(10*1)+(9*1)+(8*4)+(7*3)+(6*2)+(5*0)+(4*7)+(3*8)+(2*9)+(1*10) = 133. actually correct answer is 164.

Comment: yeah, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Simpler way:

```
public static int sum(String input) {

    int sum = 0, temp = 0, i = 0;

    for (char a : input.toCharArray()) {
        temp = a == 'x' ? 10 : a == '?' ? 0 : Character.getNumericValue(a);
        sum += temp * (10 - i++);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But in terms of Code Quality, does it make much difference?

Comment: In code posted in question, `input.charAt(i)` is a repeated, recursive call and got removed here. With `foreach loop`, there is no need to pass, evaluate length of array.